# While upgrading to react 16.9 - getting an error: "Please update the following components: t"

Tags: reactjs

While upgrading to React 16.9 i am getting the following error. The problem is that i do not have component named: "t". how can i get the real name of it? I don't have unsafe methods on my code so i assume its related to 3rd party lib.

> > bundle.js:174471 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use
>
> - Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
> - If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static
>     getDerivedStateFromProps. Learn more at:
> - Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the
>     UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their
>     new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in
>     your project source folder.
>
> **Please update the following components: t**

Comment: Do a global search for "componentWillReceiveProps" in the code?

Comment: I did... Its not part of my code

Comment: Do a global search for "componentWillReceiveProps" in node_modules?

Comment: I had a similar problem. I searched in my code but I couldn't find it. At the end of the error message I saw "Please update the following components: Link, Redirect, ...". After upgrading the regarding packages (reat-router-dom in my case) the message was gone.

Comment: In my case the message is this: Please update the following components: `GraphiQL`, `QueryHistory`

Comment: There is more information about this situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647771/react-reactstrap-warning-legacy-context-api-has-been-detected-within-a-strict)

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same after upgrading to React 16.9.

It is not easy to track down the root of the warnings (I switched parts of the code on/off until I had the warning isolated).

For me it turned out to be the `react-moment` library. There's an open issue in that project to resolve the warning: https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment/issues/96

Answer (score -4):

Is Deprecated lifecycles warning when using react 16.9.0

[React 16.9 Deprecation *Will* warning](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1374)

Comment: i know that. My question was how can i find the real component name of in order to fix it.

Comment: Are you running in npm start or npm build mode?