# Errors while using context for authentication in a login form (Firebase & React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-context

I've created a login form and accessing states through a context api. Can't seem to find a problem in my code but these errors are showing up:

Errors: 1-Legacy context API has been detected within a strict-mode tree...
2-findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which
is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.

Code:

```
import React,{useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {auth} from '../firebase/firebase';

const AuthContext= React.createContext();

export function useAuth(){
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
    const[currentUser,setCurrentUser]= useState();

    function login(email, password){
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
     const unsubscriber= auth.onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
        setCurrentUser(user)
            })
     
     return unsubscriber
    },[])

    const value={
        currentUser,
        login
    }
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
// Login form//

import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import './login.css';
import {Button, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label} from 'reactstrap';
import {useAuth} from '../../context/AuthContext'
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';



const Login=()=> {

  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef=useRef();
  const {login} = useAuth();
  const[error,setError]=useState();

  async function handlesubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
      setError('')
      await login(emailRef.current.value,passwordRef.current.value)
    }
    catch{
      setError("Failed to Login")
    }
    
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <Form className='login-form' onSubmit={handlesubmit}>
          {error && <Alert color="danger">{error}</Alert>}
            <h1 className='website'><span className='font-weight-bold'>ApniShop</span>.com</h1>
            <FormGroup>
                <label>Email</label>
                <Input name='email' type='text' placeholder='Email' ref={emailRef}/>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
                <label>Password</label>
                <Input name='password' type='password' placeholder='password' ref={passwordRef}/>
            </FormGroup>
            <Button className='btn-lg btn-block' outline color ="danger" type='submit'>Log in</Button>
        </Form>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: HI, why you are using ref for email and password inputs?

Comment: To get my inputs from the form. Although it can be done through states as well.

Comment: You are using await login(...), but login it is not an async function. I think return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) it is not necessary, calling auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) it will be enough

Comment: This is related to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61647771/react-reactstrap-warning-legacy-context-api-has-been-detected-within-a-strict

Comment: The problem is resolved by using states instead of refs.